# access to json object trow error

Tags: javascript, json

I've the following json and I want to get the property value like following

```
{
  "Actions": [
    {
      "save": {
        "path": "/save",
        "function": "saveFn"

      },
      "reload": {
        "path": "/delete",
        "function": "deleteFn"

      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to get the function property so it try like following which give error of undefined

```
var config = require("../file");

            for (var i = 0; i < config.actions.length; i++) {
```

Here is the error

```
config.actions[i].function
```

Comment: Well.. it is called "Actions", with a capital.

Comment: Make sure you do an `eval()` before you try to treat the object as json. i.e. : `config = eval( "json string" )`

Comment: `config.actions[i].save.function` or `config.actions[i].reload.function`

Comment: @Ahmad: Don't use `eval`. There are better ways to parse JSON.

Comment: @Ahmad, @Cerbrus, in Node.js `require`-ing a .json file parses it automatically. Usage in OP is correct

Comment: @KirillSlatin: Ah, that's good to know (I never worked with Node.js). In that case this question can be closed as "Typo".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your root is called "Action" , not "action". And with your "Actions" is ONE array with multiple values, so you should fetch them like:

```
var config = require("../file");
for(key in config.Actions[0]){
    console.log(config.Actions[0][key].function)
};
```